# Javascript Multiple Extended Signature Test(1)(2)(3) or Test(1)(2,3)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to create a function in JavaScript which allow me to do something like below:

```
test(1,2,3)
test(1)(2,3)
test(1)(2)(3)
```

I was thinking of something below: 
Unsure what this is called.

```
function test(a)
{
    return function(b,c) { return a+b+c; }
}
```

I was looking into Fat arrow function and nothing is mentioned about this.
Unsure if this is a new ES6 or ES7 function.

Comment: The code that you posted does work. The technique is called [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Comment: Awesome! I had problem trying to find the technique name!

Comment: is it possible to do something along this line:
var ddTest= cu(test) = > {return test};

Then I can just go 

ddTest(1,2,3)
ddTest(1)(2,3)
ddTest(1)(2)(3)

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have native support for currying. If you search on Stack Overflow, you will find custom solutions. Also, ES7 only has two new features and none of them have anything to do with functions.